# Setting tag on Dynamic UITextfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

If I create a UITextField programmatically, will it have a value for the tag? Can I set a value for the tag? Basically I have an app that allows someone to hit a plus sign and a new uitextfield is created. I need to capture the value of the textfield and track which field that value was for. I was using the tag property to determine which uitextfield was which and then storing it according. Basically, I wanted to assign a unique id to each uitextfield. Is it possible to set the tag? I know I can extend the UITextField class and achieve it that way. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

`tag` is a property of `UIView`.  A `UITextField` is a type of `UIView`.  Therefore, you already have a tag property available in your `UITextField`.

Its default value should be 0 but it's certainly writable, so something like `textField.tag = 42;` is valid.